# Difference between horizontal and oblique projectile motion

Tags: kinematics, projectile

I have been studying kinematics and I am stuck with understanding what is oblique projectile and what is horizontal projectile and what is the difference between them?

Can someone please explain them to me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Horizontal projectile means throwing objects in one dimension. For example,(1.) if you throw a ball parallel to the ground then it is said to be an oblique projectile. (2.)If you throw vertically upward it is said to be a vertical projectile. (3.) If you throw in between the above-mentioned two states then it is said to be oblique projectile.

Example:

1. if θ = 0 (with respect to ground), it is a horizontal projection.
2. if θ = 90 (with respect to ground), it is vertical projection.
3. if θ = 0 < θ < 90 (with respect to ground), it is oblique projection.